# How to get row value in context menu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contextmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Get Row values in Context menu using cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212110/how-to-get-row-values-in-context-menu-using-cursor)

I have created a `ContextMenu` and used the following code:

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){

            switch(item.getItemId())
            {

            case R.id.Show_Note:

                 //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

                 Intent i=new Intent(this, ShowNote.class);
                    Cursor c = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                    int item_id = c.getInt(0);
                    i.putExtra("item_id", item_id );
                    startActivity(i);

                break
```

It returns first row value every time, by pressing any list item. Please suggest, How to get pressed row value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to move your Cursor at the specified position. Before getting data from it.

```
c.moveToPosition(position);
```

Add this line in your code and let me know what happen..

Your code something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowNote.class);
Cursor c = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
c.moveToPosition(position); // This line need to be added here 
int item_id = c.getInt(0);
i.putExtra("item_id", item_id );
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks...Also can you please let me know how can I delete the row. as I have database method and how to call delete method in context menu???

Comment: thanks, Can you please let me know how to delete row???

Comment: Do you have written delete query for your database?

Answer (score 0):

How is position set?

In order to get the position in the list view you can add the following two lines to the beginning of your item selection method:

```
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        int position = info.position;

        switch(item.getItemId())
                {

                case R.id.Show_Note:

                     //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=
                     (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

                     Intent i=new Intent(this, ShowNote.class);
                        Cursor c = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                        int item_id = c.getInt(0);
                        i.putExtra("item_id", item_id );
                        startActivity(i);

                    break
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks yes done with show note but can you tell me the delete note. How to delete one row using context menu.